# error while writing Dataframe into HDFS path

Tags: apache-spark

while writing a Dataframe into HDFS path failed

```
df_export_data.write.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter","|").partitionBy("sales_org_cd").mode("append").save("/tmp/test/")
```

> Error message:
>   --------------
>   19/05/22 19:36:56 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 5589473205747598389 java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.scheduler.AskPermissionToCommitOutput; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6126279111580845008, local class serialVersionUID = -6906932408541757372
>   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751

Comment: check whether you have permissions on this folder .save("/tmp/test/") to write  in hdfs

Comment: I do have access.

Comment: @RavichandraKancharla Did you find a solution for this? Please post the answer if you did.